# Whoever does not gather with me --

Tags: greek

Luke 11:23, [NIV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=luke%2011%3A23&version=NIV):

> Whoever is not with me is against me, and whoever does not gather with me scatters.

The [Greek](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%2011:21-23&version=MOUNCE):

> ho eimi mē meta egō eimi kata egō kai ho mē synagō meta egō

There's no "scatters", so I assume this has to be an ellipsis understood by parallelism. I don't have enough Greek to figure out how that's deduced, and I'm curious. Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: The [Biblehub Interlinear](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/luke/11-23.htm) makes it clear. Your quotation misses out the last two words _emou skorpizei_. ( ... me, scatters.)

Comment: I wonder if the opposite is true too? That is: "Whoever is not against me is for me, and whoever is not scattering away from me gathers."

Comment: @Constantthin No doubt a good case could be made based on Luke 9:50, which occurs so close to this one and directly reverses the first half. It might have been asked about on this site already.

Comment: use BIB and ABP interlinear using theword.net free bible software, and use stepbible. org

Comment: youre quoting a reverse interlinear, which shows Greek word order based on English translation. Berean Bible has also one reverse interlinear but its not that bad as Mounce which is missing words. You should not be reading interlinear unless you have started learning Greek. I suggest John Dobson, duolingo. Stepbible is perfect for basic interlinear or word lexicon finding.

Comment: @Michael16 Thanks. I do have a really good physical interlinear as well in the traditional style and with lots more info (including parsing, which I can get some mileage out of because of my linguistics training). The main thing I use the online one for is easy clicking from Greek word to glossary entry, but I see it's not the only game in town with that convenience. I'll try Stepbible next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Greek of Luke 11:23 is actually (the OP's source is spurious and incomplete):

> Ὁ μὴ ὢν μετ’ ἐμοῦ κατ’ ἐμοῦ ἐστιν, καὶ ὁ μὴ συνάγων μετ’ ἐμοῦ
> σκορπίζει.

The BLB gives a good literal rendering as:

> The one not being with Me is against Me; and the one not gathering
> with Me scatters.

Note that the final verb σκορπίζει (skorpizei) means: "*I disperse, scatter abroad (as of sheep); I dissipate, waste; I distribute alms*." (Strongs).

To remove any doubt, here is a better source of an interlinear taken from  https://biblehub.com/interlinear/luke/11-23.htm

[image]

[Note: I am mystified by the almost garbled interlinear in the OP's source which makes no sense; I assume it is the result of sloppy type-setting or some other transcription error.]

Comment: A straightforward answer, then. That sucks! I've often used the Mounce interlinear I linked to and now I learn it's defective. Time to switch.